# Rails - How do I add value to my users table from my Payment model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, stripe-payments

I have tried for hours to figure this out. I can successfully make payments with this code in my Payment model payment.rb:

```
def save_with_payment
if valid?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, card: stripe_card_token)
  self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
  save!

  Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => (total * 100).to_i, # in cents
      :currency => "usd",
      :customer => customer.id
  )
end
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
false
end
```

I want to save Stripe's customer.id to my users table attribute customer_id in my User model but the above code is in my Payment model, how do I do that?

Stripe's help section says this is easy by doing the following:

```
save_stripe_customer_id(user, customer.id)
```

then later:

```
customer_id = get_stripe_customer_id(user)

Stripe::Charge.create(
:amount => 1500, # $15.00 this time
:currency => "usd",
:customer => customer_id
)
```

What code do I put in save_stripe_customer_id? Where do I put that code? The above method that is working for me that is producing Stripe's customer.id is in the Payment model but I want to save it as an attribute in my User model so I can charge the user later without them having to reenter their credit card. How do I save something that is produced in the Payment model into my users table?

EDIT:

payment.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
has_many :payments
```

The attribute that I want to add to my users table as customer_id is already in my payments table as stripe_customer_token, I just can't figure out how to use it in there or how to transfer it over to my users table.

MORE:

payments_controller.rb:

```
def create
if current_user
  @payment = current_user.payments.new(params[:payment])
else
  @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])
end
respond_to do |format|
  if @payment.save_with_payment
    format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @payment, status: :created, location: @payment }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end
```

Could the reason that

```
self.user.update_attribute(customer_id, customer.id)
```

is throwing an undefined method for customer_id be somehow related to Devise because user is involved? Is there something I need to change in my routes file?

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts' do
get 'users', :to => 'store#index', :as => :user_root
end

resources :users

resources :payments

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

Comment: How payment and user models relate to each other?

Comment: Have you tried `self.user` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
def save_with_payment
if valid?
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, card: stripe_card_token)
  self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
  self.user.update_attribute(:customer_id, customer.id) #this will update your user
  save!

  Stripe::Charge.create(
      :amount => (total * 100).to_i, # in cents
      :currency => "usd",
      :customer => customer.id
  )
end
rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
false
end
```

Comment: gives me this error: undefined local variable or method `customer_id' for #<Payment:0x007fc775ecbf28> but customer_id is a field in the users table

Comment: strange, are you sure you've copied my line of code properly? `self.user.update_attribute(customer_id, customer.id)`

Comment: yes just repasted it in from your comment and tried again, same error

Comment: I'm using Devise could that be the cause somehow because it involves user?

Comment: oh man we were so close, your line of code was missing the colon sign in front of customer_id, should have been :customer_id, edit your answer and I'll accept it